# Click javascript tab using mechanize and ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mechanize

I am using mechanize, ruby and ruby & rails to scrape this [website](https://www.camara.cl/camara/diputado_detalle.aspx?prmid=968) . 
And i want to click the "Trabajo En Sala" tab so that I could scrape whatever information in that tab.

I know that mechanize doesn't support javascript, but i read it [here](https://josephjefferson.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/ruby-mechanize-and-javascript-postback/) how this guy is using mechanize to handle the javascript response. And one thing I noticed, I have more or less the same problem and could probably use the same solution like he did. The reasons being:

**1)** **The tab href is using the same __doPostBack() function**

```
<a id="ctl00_mainPlaceHolder_btnSala" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$mainPlaceHolder$btnSala','')">Trabajo en sala</a>
```

[image]

**2)**  **When I look at the source code, I could clearly see the form which is related to the javascript __doPostBack function:**

[image]

So I have read the post of that guy wrote and tried to modified his solution into mine. And this is what I got so far:

```
require 'mechanize'

task :scraper_test => [:environment] do

    agent = Mechanize.new

    page = agent.get("https://www.camara.cl/camara/diputado_detalle.aspx?prmid=968")

    form = page.form("aspnetForm.add_field!('__EVENTTARGET','')")
    form.add_field!('ctl00$mainPlaceHolder$btnSala','')
    tab = agent.submit(form)

end
```

*p/s: im using rake within rails app to run this.*

But when i run it, I got this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `add_field!' for nil:NilClass
```

So, can you help me to figure out the right way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran this in my console and you're getting this error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `add_field!' for nil:NilClass

because this line returns nil

```
form = page.form("aspnetForm.add_field!('__EVENTTARGET','')")
```

Change it to this and it will fix that current error.

```
form = page.form("aspnetForm")
```